# Set visible interface from method/class

Tags: java, graphics, hangman

I started feeling like my code was becoming a little cluttered in the graphics:

```
void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawImage(chalkBoard, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

    g.drawImage(gallows, 0, 65, gallows.getWidth(), gallows.getHeight(),
            null);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 38));
    g.drawString("Hangman", 45, 58);
    g.drawString("X", 445, 58);

    g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 15));
    g.drawString("Xid Studios", 200, 58);

    if (currentState == State.START_MENU) {
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
        g.drawString("One Player", 240, 100);
        g.drawImage(btnBorder, 233, 75, 150, 33, null);
        g.drawImage(startDisplayHanger, 240, 90, 56, 128, null);

        g.drawString("Two Players", 240, 225);
        g.drawImage(btnBorder, 233, 200, 175, 33, null);
        g.drawImage(startDisplayHanger, 240, 220, 56, 128, null);
        g.drawImage(startDisplayHanger, 296, 220, 56, 128, null);

    } else if ((currentState == State.PLAYER_ONE_MENU)
            || (currentState == State.PLAYER_TWO_MENU)) {

        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
        g.drawString("PLAY", 400, 330);
        g.drawImage(btnBorder, 390, 295, 80, 50, null);

        if (currentState == State.PLAYER_ONE_MENU) {
            g.drawString("Player One's Name", 240, 100);
            // g.drawString(playerOne, 240, 125);
            g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 20));
            for (int p = 0; p < pOne.length; p++) {
                g.drawString(pOne[p], 240 + (p * 15), 125);
            }
            g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
            g.drawString("Categories", 240, 175);
            g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 15));
            for (int c = 0; c < categories.length; c++) {
                g.drawString(categories[c], 250, 200 + (c * 15));
            }

        } else if (currentState == State.PLAYER_TWO_MENU) {
            g.drawString("Player One's Name", 240, 100);
            g.drawString("Player Two's Name", 240, 175);
            g.drawString("Custom Puzzle:", 240, 250);
            g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 15));
            g.drawString("6 Letters Max", 240, 262);

        }
    } else if (currentState == State.PLAY_SCREEN) {
        setHangerImage();
        g.drawImage(line, 225, 290, 225, 26, null);
        g.drawImage(hanger, 80, 90, 113, 256, null);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 31));
        g.drawString(chancesLeft + "", 100, 330);

        g.drawString("Player One", 240, 100);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 20));
        for (int p = 0; p < pOne.length; p++) {
            g.drawString(pOne[p], 240 + (p * 20), 125);
        }

        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
        if (puzzleCreated) {
            for (int x = 0; x < puzLength; x++) {
                g.drawString("" + hid[x], 250 + (x * 20), 330);
            }
        }
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 31));
        g.drawString("Category:", 240, 160);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 20));
        g.drawString(category, 240, 185);
    } else if (currentState == State.LOSE_SCREEN) {
        g.drawImage(line, 225, 290, 225, 26, null);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
        g.drawString("LOSE", 100, 330);
        // setHangerImage();
        g.drawImage(hanger, 80, 90, 113, 256, null);
        for (int x = 0; x < puzLength; x++) {
            g.drawString("" + puzzleSplit[x], 250 + (x * 20), 330);
        }

    } else if (currentState == State.WIN_SCREEN) {
        g.drawImage(line, 225, 290, 225, 26, null);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
        g.drawString("WIN", 100, 330);
        // setHangerImage();
        g.drawImage(hanger, 80, 90, 113, 256, null);
        for (int x = 0; x < puzLength; x++) {
            g.drawString("" + puzzleSplit[x], 250 + (x * 20), 330);
        }
    }

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

State is an enum that i created to differentiate the states of the game.

```
public enum State {
    START_MENU,
    PLAYER_ONE_MENU,
    PLAYER_TWO_MENU,
    WIN_SCREEN,
    LOSE_SCREEN,
    PLAY_SCREEN
}
```

Would it be possible to put each part into a separate method/class and then call it and how would I go about it?

I was thinking about maybe:

```
if (currentState == State.START_SCREEN) {
    drawStartMenu();
}
```

I was wondering if anybody knows how to do this or has a better way of rendering the screen and if they could help me with this.

If you want to see how I'm using this, check out [this](https://github.com/Xid-Studios/Hangman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, If possible then avoid switch because

- Using a switch is a sign of code smell.
- Switch statement can be replaced by polymorphism(InternalPolymorphisim)

For more info just google or [read](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell)

Secondly use inheritance where its really need , [otherwise prefer composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Below is how we can refactor the code

You can create a map in the class where you have created the method **void render()** , like this

```
private static final Map<State, IRenderer> RENDERERS_MAP;
```

We declared a hash map which is static -> meaning class member and final -> so that it can be initialized only once. Since we want to use enum types as hash map keys , we will use create map's instance using EnumMap

We can initialize the map in static block(static block is executed ONLY once , no matter how many objects you create).

```
    static { 
    RENDERERS_MAP= new EnumMap<State, IRenderer>(State.class);

   for (State state : State.values()) {
        RENDERERS_MAP.put(state, getRender());
   }
}
```

**NOTE** If you want to avoid using static block then just move the code from static block into a static method and call it like this

```
private static final Map<State, IRenderer> m = getMap();
```

Now the method **render()(which you pasted above)** can be refactor like this(that the beauty of OOP) :

```
void render() {
    Renderer currentRenderer = RENDERERS_MAP.get(currentState);
    if (ren  != null) {
        currentRenderer.render();
     }
}
```

The **Enum State** , can be refactored to include information about renderer

```
public enum State {
    START_MENU() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return new StartMenuRenderer();
        }
    },
    PLAYER_ONE_MENU() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return new PlayerOneRenderer();
        }
    },
    PLAYER_TWO_MENU() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return new PlayerTwoRenderer();
        }
    },
    WIN_SCREEN() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return null;  //TODO: implement body
        }
    },
    LOSE_SCREEN() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return null;  //TODO: implement body
        }
    },
    PLAY_SCREEN() {
        @Override
        public Renderer getRenderer() {
            return null;  //TODO: implement body
        }
    };

    public abstract Renderer getRenderer();
}
```

The interface Renderer look like this(you can change it according to your needs)

```
public interface Renderer {

    void render(Graphics2D g);
}
```

Now we can create classes which implements Renderer using [Single_responsibility_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

```
public class StartMenuRenderer implements Renderer {
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        //TODO: implement body
    }
}
```

And Since there is some common logic shared between PlayerOne and PlayerTwo We can create a class called PlayerMenuRenderer like this

```
public abstract class PlayerMenuRenderer implements Renderer {

     protected void init(Graphics2D g) {
         g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
         g.drawString("PLAY", 400, 330);
         g.drawImage(btnBorder, 390, 295, 80, 50, null);
     }

}
```

And subclasses **PlayerOneRenderer** and **PlayerTwoRenderer** can be created like this

```
public class PlayerOneRenderer extends PlayerMenuRenderer {
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        init(g);
        //TODO: implement body
    }
}


public class PlayerTwoRenderer extends PlayerMenuRenderer {
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        init(g);
        //TODO: implement body
    }
}
```

Comment: i understood everything except the first 2 bits of code, could you explain how they work in more detail?

Comment: @Exikle , by **first 2 bits** i guess you mean the code regarding with Map creation and static block. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

To answer real fast about your switch, you can do the following :

```java
function whatEverName(State state){

    switch(state){
         case START_MENU:
             drawStartMenu();
             //..
             break;
         case PLAYER_ONE_MENU:
             //..
             break;
         case START_MENU:
             //..
             break;
    //...
         default:
             //..
             break;
    } 
}
```

---

By the length of that function, it could be cut into more functions,  but even more it could closely be a class itself.

Anyway, If I were you, I'd make the function with the switch as short as possible. Probably only the switch itself. Separate the initialization of the `Graphics2D`, from the switch. The shortest and the more specific the methods are, the easier to test.

So put from `BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();` to `g.drawString("Xid Studios", 200, 58);` in a function (all on his own). Then, everything that is in a if clause presently should get his own method, try have methods of 20 and less lines.

*When I say 20 lines, don`t count braces or wrapped line. Only lines of code.*

---

Also I've seen that you wanted to call one method `drawSTARTMENU`, the name is verbose,(that's great) but try staying in the Java conventions which are camelCase method name. It's OK to capitalize an acronym (eg: URL) but try to keep words in lowercase, and caps only the first letter of any word following the first one. That make the code easier to read and makes all the code look the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to a small degree with Hugo about seperating all the graphics portions within each if statement. But this is a prime example of how inheritance comes to play. You have a switch statement inside your logic method (some people have different names for this, but it basically just means where you do all the work)

You are on the right track with having a state. You are also on the right track with having a enum. Where I feel that you go wrong is by putting all those in the logic method (in this case render) So I would make a abstract class that returns a instance of itself based upon the state. It would have 1 abstract method called render.

```
public abstract class AbstractWindowBufferStrategy
{
    public static AbstractWindowBufferStrategy(State state, BufferStrategy bs)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case START_MENU:
                return new StartMenuBufferStrategy(bs);
            case PLAYER_ONE_MENU:
                return new PlayerOneMenuBufferStrategy(bs);
            case PLAYER_TWO_MENU:
                return new PlayerTwoMenuBufferStrategy(bs);
            case WIN_SCREEN:
                return new WinScreenBufferStrategy(bs);
            case LOSE_SCREEN:
                return new LoseScreenBufferStrategy(bs);
            case PLAY_SCREEN:
                return new PlayScreenBufferStrategy(bs);
        }
        abstract void render();
    }
}
public class StartMenuBufferStrategy extends AbstractWindowBufferStragey
{
    public StartmenuBufferStrategy(BufferStrategy bs)
    {
        //do something with bs to set g
    }
    private Graphics2D g;
    public void renderRest()
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(chalkBoard, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        g.drawImage(gallows, 0, 65, gallows.getWidth(), gallows.getHeight(), null);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 38));
        g.drawString("Hangman", 45, 58);
        g.drawString("X", 445, 58);

        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 15));
        g.drawString("Xid Studios", 200, 58);
        g.setFont(dFont.deriveFont((float) 28));
        g.drawString("One Player", 240, 100);
        g.drawImage(btnBorder, 233, 75, 150, 33, null);
        g.drawImage(startDisplayHanger, 240, 90, 56, 128, null);

        g.drawString("Two Players", 240, 225);
        g.drawImage(btnBorder, 233, 200, 175, 33, null);
        g.drawImage(startDisplayHanger, 240, 220, 56, 128, null);
        g.drawImage(startDisplayHanger, 296, 220, 56, 128, null);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show(); //might want to change to setVisible(true) to keep current.
    }
}
//etc for rest of the classes
```

now you will be able to do somethign like this

```
public void foo()
{
    AbstractWindowBufferStrategy awbs = AbstractWindowBufferStrategy.getBufferStrategy(currentState, bs);
    //will never have to change. It depends on a difficult to change abstract class.
    awbs.render(); 
}
```

for extra points you can figure out how to put the common render portion into the abstract class, and have all the child classes do only what they need to.

Comment: what do you mean "do something with bs to set g"

Comment: I actually have no idea what you did. Sorry, I've never done any abstract anything, and I'm relatively new to using buffered anything

Comment: @Exikle I mean that in your draw method you check if bs is null. If it is you created a buffer strategy. So in this case you'd move that code to your constructor. You then take the graphics from BufferStrategy and set it to g. Hence my comment of Do something with bs to set g.

Comment: @Exikle Using abstract classes has nothing to do with Buffered Strategy. This particular case is Polymorphism. Something I would recommend researching as it is what you are trying to do, but Polymorphism is the clean way of doing it.

Comment: @Exikle I found a good article on Java website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html